# Disable web Inspector in release mode - bb10 webworks

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

How to disable web inspector in release mode?..I am developing blackberry 10 app using webworks...By default when i open the application the alert "web inspector mode enabled" is showing..can any one suggest some ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just use 2 commands:

1) Build in release mode

```
webworks build --release -k keypassword
```

2) Deploy to BB 10 without build option

```
webworks run --no-build --devicepass devicepassword
```