# How to remove alert which comes on startup on BB10 device

Tags: blackberry-10

I am building app BB10 devices and it is workling fine but when i launch the app, alert is showing web inspector enabled with some ip address.

I used webworks 2.0 for building this app.

What is way to hide this alert on BB10 device.

Comment: Not related to Worklight at all; If you enabled the inspector, you'll see an alert. Removing Worklight tag, adding blackberry tags.

Answer (score 0):

Follow BlackBerry 10 guides for this. For example:

- [Disable web Inspector in release mode - bb10 webworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773346/disable-web-inspector-in-release-mode-bb10-webworks)

  > Just use 2 commands:
  >
  > 1) Build in release mode
  >
  > ```
  > webworks build --release -k keypassword
  > ```
  >
  > 2) Deploy to BB 10 without build option
  >
  > ```
  > webworks run --no-build --devicepass devicepassword
  > ```
- Search in Google for [Blackberry how to not disable inspector alert](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=blackberry%20how%20to%20not%20disable%20inspector%20alert&safe=off)

Sounds like you need to not use Inspector if you don't want the Inspector alert.